# MonoTouch.Dialog double

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I use the .net `propertyGrid` a lot to edit objects.

The MonoTouch.Dialog allows much of the same functionality for iOS.  But it needs a way to simply allow double's to be displayed and edited. Float uses a trackbar - which can be useful sometimes, but not for entering data like a price, etc.  Am I missing something?